# Groupby multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to sum up values in 20 different columns based on common enteries in the 'VALUE' column

Here is how I do it for a single column:

```
df.groupby('VALUE').aggregate({'COUNT':numpy.sum},as_index=False)
```

Is there a better way to extend it for 20 columns where I do not write their names out explicitly? I.e, I would like a way to just pass a list of column names.

Please see hernamesbarbara's answer below for an example that can be used to illustrate thhis issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select which columns to sum with a list of column names using sub notation on the pandas group. Is this what you're looking for?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "dim1":  [np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar']) for _ in range(10)],
    "measure1":  np.random.random_integers(0, 100, 10),
    "measure2":  np.random.random_integers(0, 100, 10)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

Out[1]:
  dim1  measure1  measure2
0  bar         9        86
1  bar        24        64
2  bar        47        46
3  foo        60        98
4  bar        94        53
5  foo        95        89
6  foo        98         9
7  bar         4        95
8  foo        63        66
9  foo        40        47

df.groupby(['dim1'])['measure1', 'measure2'].sum()

Out[2]:
      measure1  measure2
dim1
bar        178       344
foo        356       309
```

**update 2015-01-02** *Delayed reply to a comment below, but better late than never*

If you don't know how many columns you have but you do know the column naming convention, construct a list of columns to aggregate dynamically. here's one way:

```
colnames = ["measure".format(i+1) for i in range(100)]  # make 100 fake columns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10, 100)), columns=colnames)
df['dim1'] = [np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar']) for _ in range(10)]   # add fake dimension to groupby

desired_columns = [col for col in df.columns if "94" in col or "95" in col]   # select columns 94 and 95

df.groupby(['dim1'])[desired_columns].sum()

Out[52]:
      measure94  measure95
dim1
bar           4          4
foo           6          6
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. In my case, there are around 30 columns: 'measure1', 'measure2'... 'measure30'. However, I only want to apply sum() to 'measure1' ... 'measure20'. is there a way df.groupby(['dim1'])['measure1', 'measure2'].sum() can be written without having to write all 20 column names. This is important because some of my column names are generated programatically, and I do not know their names beforehand.

Comment: ok, moved column names to a list. it will now do what I want. thanks!